# Formatting Summary report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have created summary report but i like to add some text along with the sub total how can i do that?

for an example I have added here `Account CC Sub Total`

```
Serial Number     Amount         Credit Amount
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Account CC Sub Total: ZZZZZZZZ   ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Comment: Nick -- Current SFDC OOB reporting is exceptionally limited in formatting options. You need to go to third party packages that exploit report templates like Conga to accomplish this (or use VF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With custom formula fields in summary reports the output is either number percent or currency. You cannot display text. I think you may have to do a formula field that you could summarize by to get the text you want then do the formula field to sum the amount to get that total.

Comment: understood but how can i have that at the bottom of the each group? i have played much but could not able to figured out, the only way its displaying is  column not at the group level

Comment: I don't think you could add it at the bottom. Default summary values go at the top of the group. Another thing you could do in a dashboard is make a metric component and then you can type in text next to your summary amount.